# Basic steps to develop python API in Unix environment

Tags: command-line, python, path

I am developing an API in Unix environment for virtual machines. Most of the modules are developed in python. I have few questions on this.

I have the file extension as `abc.py`. I would like to make this as a command. For example , `virtman dominfo [vmid]` should be the command syntax. Now I have to give `./virtman.py dominfo [vmid]` to achieve this.  And I have first line as `#!/usr/bin/python` in the python file. So how can make this as a command?

My echo $PATH looks like '/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin0'

I read a lot of articles but I didn't get the clear picture,so any hints/suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @Anthon - I edited the question

Comment: Are you going to post the other part as a question as well?

Comment: Yes I will add another question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mistaken in that `abc.py` would not be a command. If you can execute it, then is, just one with a dot in the name. Execute in the sense that you can do `./abc.py`, so the execute bits must be set. If you **have** to do `python abc.py` than you it is not a command (yet).

In general, to make a normal  python file `abc.py` executable you should make sure the first line reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

(This assumes you have `/usr/bin/env` as a program, and that will find the `python` command, which might be in `/usr/local/bin`. It also assumes that you want to run the default `python` (which is normally a link to a particular python version like `python2.7`), you could also use `python3` if that is available as a command).

After that do

```
chmod +x abc.py
mv abc.py abc
```

And then you can run `./abc`. If the current directory is in your path, or if you move `abc` to a directory in your path, you should be able to execute `abc` from anywhere.¹

There are however disadvantages of renaming and moving the file:

- you can no longer to `from abc import SomeClass`, as the file is renamed
- If the file is under revision control it might no longer be

So instead, what I normally do, is make a new file `/usr/local/bin/abc` that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from abc import main
main()
```

and have at the bottom of `abc.py`:

```
def main():
    doing the real stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The directory of `abc.py` needs to be in the PATH python searches for modules, but this way it doesn't have to be changed, and can be used by any program as an import, and started as `python abc.py`.

¹ <sub>The `mv` is necessary to get rid of the dot in the command name, but not really necessary, you can invoke `./abc.py` if you don't rename it.</sub>

Comment: This seems to be working, But I want to execute only 'abc' not './abc' . For example how 'uptime' works or any ohter commands in unix

Comment: @DineshAppavoo For that the command must be in one of the directories in your $PATH, can you add the output of `echo $PATH` at the end of your question?

Comment: I added the echo $PATH output

Comment: @DineshAppavoo I put some more PATH related stuff in the answer to your other question. I hope that moves you forward a bit.

Comment: In `/usr/local/bin/abc` how to you set the path to `abc.py` for the import? Do you just use `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/git/repo/abc.py')`?

Comment: @dotancohen no just the path `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/git/repo)`, and make sure there is an (empty) file there with name `__init__.py` (double underscores in front and before the dot).

Comment: Thanks, Anthon. I tried to set up an example for the OP, but it is throwing "ImportError: cannot import name main". If might might take a look, I've posting the details on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cNQM0Lih).

Comment: @dotancohen The problem is the abc.py in `foo.py` try `import abc; print abc.__file__` you are most likely importing the `abc.py` from the standard library (Abstract base classes). So rename that file, or do `from pypackage.abc import main` and leave out the `sys.insert()`.

Comment: That was it, Anthon! I didn't even know about the `abc` library, and even had I known about it I would have thought that inserting at location 0 would have overridden it. I see that is not the case. **Thank you!**

Comment: @Anthon - This helped me a lot. I appreciate your effort for the answer.

Comment: @dotancohen - Your example narrowed my results. It was very helpul

Answer (score 1):

Anthon's answer is correct, however for non-trivial Python projects you should have a look at the [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) module in the standard library. It's *designed* to deploy python modules and executables on a system the "right way", and :

- Python devs are familiar with this module (or should be) because it's in the standard library and most well-known Python packages (Django, NumPy, Celery to name a few) are using it. Newcomers will know instantly how to deploy your project.
- Once you've defined which files and packages you have in your project, just run  `python setup.py install` to deploy and update your package on the system.

  No more manually updating the `PATH` variable copying files to `/usr/local/bin` or setting them to be executable, it's all handled for you!
- You can use `pip install -e` to install your package in development mode.
- It's portable (sort of) in Windows or OSX environments as well.

Also, I can't recomment the use of an argument parser such as [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) enough if you're designing command-line tools.